# Minus sign when changing limits in definite integration

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I have

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\left(x-2\right)\sqrt{x^{2}+x+1}}$$

Calculating the integral
$\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx$ gives (approx) `−0.515374173193`

However, if I perform the following substitution into the integral and put the limits in terms of
`t`

Let $(x-2) = 1/t$

$dx=-\frac{1}{t^{2}}dt$

When $x=0$ we have $t=-1/2$

When $x=1$ we have $t=-1$

After some simplification, the integral now becomes

$$
-\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{7t^{2}+5t+1}}dt
$$

Which is `0.515374173193`, exactly negative of what we started with, why does this happen?

Desmos link:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rg0xx0e6nd

Comment: Are you sure you substituted the variables correctly?

Comment: Yes because $\int_a^b f=-\int_b^a f$. In particular, the bounds on your integral are $a>b$

Comment: @Andrew Why would the limits flip here

Comment: I am saying that you did it wrong. You wrote the integral $\int_{-1/2}^{-1}$

Comment: @Andrew My limits were from x=0 to x=1, so they shouldn't they be from t=-1/2 to t=-1?

Comment: If you show the complete way how you arrived at the new integral it would be much easier to detect the flaw.

Comment: By the way, the exact solution is  $$-\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}\,\coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{7} \left(13+4   \sqrt{3}\right)}\right)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At one point before you got the form of the integral which you displayed at the end (which is not correct), I suppose you must have had something like this:

$$- \int_{-1/2}^{-1} \frac1{t \sqrt{\frac1{t^2} + \frac5{t} + 7}}dt$$

But (I strongly suppose) you didn't notice here that $t < 0$ inside the interval $\left[ -1, -\frac{1}{2} \right]$, and you either took $\dfrac1{t^2}$ as a common factor inside the square root and when you pulled it outside it came out as $\dfrac1{t}$ instead of what it should be: $-\dfrac{1}{t}$, or had the $t$ outside the square root go inside as $t^2$, which can't be done: you would need  to write $t$ as $-|t|$ and have the $|t|$ go inside as $t^2$, which will keep the minus sign we desire outside. Either way, with this realization now, you should have things correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure why I have 2 downvotes on my answer. It is mathematically correct and it helped the OP. I'd like to know what I might have done wrong, or what kind of etiquettes of this site I broke without knowing.